# Update dbml SQL Server Compact files

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, dbml

I'm working on a project that I did not initially do. I have created a new table in a SQL Server Compact database (`DbRecipes`).

In the Visual Studio 2010 solution, I have the `DbRecipes.dbml` Linq-to-SQL model file with the self-produced `DbRecipes.designer.cs` file from the program.

How do I do this to update the DbRecipes file with the new table?

Thanks so much

Comment: Have you tried using my SQLCE Toolbox to just generated the required code files (no dbml is required) ?

Comment: I did not try the package you named me.
I just have to add "only" to the dbml file the new table I added.